# How to concatenate Regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a new to regex and need a little help.
I can't seem to make it work when I try to concatenate on line 3.

```
var method = function(name, url) {
   name = name.replace('/[\[]/', '\\[').replace('/[\]]/', '\\]');
   var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)'); 
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    return results;
};
```

What am I missing here? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + THIS PART IS NOT BEING CONTCATENATED.
```

Comment: Do you have some example input and expected result? Also, you can inspect the regex you constructed with `.toString()`

Comment: Why do you think the concatenation isn't working? The problem is that `name.replace()` isn't working because you quoted the regexp literals.

Comment: You can do both replacements at once with `name = name.replace(/[][]/g, '\\$&')`

Comment: Your concatenation is working fine, but you are not escaping `name` correctly. See attached post how to do it.